# How do I change an image if a user clicks on open/close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
    if( $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height') == '930' ) {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','100');
      $('#desc').animate({height:'100'})
    } else {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','930');
      $('#desc').animate({height:'930'})
    }
  })
});
```

```
<a href="#" class="anchor_clicker">Click</a>
```

Right now I have text "Click" to do this but instead I want to have a default image icon when it is clicked the code above will expand the div and when clicked again it will shorten it.  how can I use two different images instead of "CLick"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sprite with your arrows, **Add a class** to your CSS that will change the background position on jQuery click. 
 Than just `toggleClass('opened')`
 [image: Arrows]

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ohecom/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.anchor_clicker').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $btn = $(this);      
    $btn.toggleClass('opened');

    var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 930 : 100 ;
    $('#desc').stop().animate({height: heights });
  }); 

});
```

CSS:

```
a.anchor_clicker{
  padding-right: 16px
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/u3GpDiC.png?1?1426) no-repeat right 0;
}
a.anchor_clicker.opened{
  background-position: right -16px;
}
```

The good part on having a **sprite** instead of 2 separate images is the removal of an additional request for the new image on click, and the time gap that is created by that request in showing the loaded new image.

Comment: I am new to JS so not sure how i would do an if/else.  but i willl look it up.  thanks!

Comment: @starbucks There you go, added an example to help you on your course. And don't forget to take a look at http://sumopaint.com I personally love it!

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, do this:

[(FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/BmL6w/1/)

**CSS**

```
.anchor_clicker
{
  background-image:url(/path/to/sprite);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
    if( $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height') == '930' ) {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','100');
      $('#desc').animate({height:'100'})
      $(this).css('background-position','-50px 0px');
    } else {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','930');
      $('#desc').animate({height:'930'});
      $(this).css('background-position','0px 0px');
    }
  })
});
```

For two images rather than a sprite:

**CSS**

```
.anchor_clicker
{
  background-image:url(/path/to/image1);
}

.anchor_clicker.b
{
  background-image:url(/path/to/image2) !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
    if( $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height') == '930' ) {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','100');
      $('#desc').animate({height:'100'})
      $(this).addClass('b');
    } else {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','930');
      $('#desc').animate({height:'930'});
      $(this).removeClass('b');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks! can you also show me another one where it's just two images rather than sprite?

Comment: @starbucks dont use 2 images. Using two images is sign of poor programming and UI skills. Why? the browser will just load the other image on click, that means that will take some time before the user sees the second image. Use sprites! :)

Comment: @rokoc.buljan I dont' use photoshop anyway to do it online?

Comment: @starbucks sure, you have a really nice free tool http://sumopaint.com Almost good as PS for such needs!

Comment: @alexmorrise i tried using yours but I can't get it to render.  How do I call this in my HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure how you set it up, but you may need to use it like the second example--add a class to change background position.

Comment: You need to change the size of the `anchor_clicker` element to be the size of the part of the sprite you're intending to use.

Comment: @alexmorrise trying to do that now but the my code to increase/decrease height is not working after I updated with your thing... any other thing I should be adding to it?

Comment: can there be a default icon that shows amongst those two images? for some reason the wrong images shows first and then the wrong image shows when clicked again.  I also checked my background-positions for those and they are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
   $(this).find('img').prop('src', function(src) {
        return src === 'img1' ? 'img2' : 'img1'
   })
})
```

You could change the `src` property of the image on the fly, based on the src. This is if you want to swap 2 different images.

But if you have a sprite with different images , then manipulating class is the way to go.